# Load Partial Views from Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm having a requirement where the number of partial views could grow tomorrow and they could be a composition of any number of values and of any type. Well, yes, I can do this using partial views itself but the time I will add a new partial add, I will be required to recompile the application that I want to avoid. It would be very like a CMS where you just specify the fields and the form is generated on the fly based on fields and their type you specify.

### **Edit 1**

Let's say for example you're building a survey application where you have multiple types of question and have associated partial views for every type. Now, if tomorrow you need to add one or more question types- how would you create a partial view dynamically on the fly for the new question type?
This is where the idea come from to store view definitions in an XML file or in Database so that the you can just add an entry for new partial view and you're good to display a new view for new question type without re-compiling > restarting your server.

> ---

Can we do something like that in ASP.NET MVC 5 using a data store (Any DB: SQL Server / MySQL or XML File / Flat File)? Any thoughts, pointers, tips are highly appreciated!

please correct if I'm incorrect.

Comment: Could you provide examppe? I didn't get it :-/

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a objectContainer that has multiple values:

Model of partial views:

```
public List<DynamicQuestion> dynamicQuestionList { get; set; }

public class DynamicQuestion
    {
        public string question{ get; set; }
        public string ask{ get; set; }
    }
```

wth that that you can get a List of DynamicQuestion so it's ok for you

in Db, you should have a table "question" that contains

```
id, question
```

that host all questions

and a table "ask" that has

```
id, idQuestion, response
```

that save all ask

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this is not what I'm expecting. suppose you have six partial views for six question types. You deployed the  application. Tomorrow, let's say you have a requirement to add another question type that has specific layout (a new partial view).

Comment: one question for one layout? you can store the layout in the "question" table under a new field, let's say "layout"?

Comment: What is the definition of a "layout" for you?

Comment: if it means html, simply use @Html.Raw(HtmlUtility.SanitizeHtml(yourDataFromDB))

Comment: well, you seem to have pointed me in the right direction... let me work on it and I'll get back to you. thanks for help @clement!

Comment: @Synny great! I'm glad to help you. If design is very different I think this is the better solution. If my anwser satisfy your need, you can consider to validate my answer :-)